# Problem calling a function that uses strtok() inside of a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

Hi i'm struggling with understanding what's wrong with my program.
My best guess is something related with this line of code here:

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

The thing is i'm trying to call a function that uses a strtok on a String passed on to it typed by the user, all of this inside of a while loop as shown in the code example below:

```
int i = 0;
char str[80];
while(i != 3){
    printf("Type in some string so i can break it: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    testFunc(str);
    printf("Loop %i ended.\n", i);
    i++;
}
return 1;
```

Result (not what i want, see further below what i actually want):

```
Type in some string so i can break it: hey there how are you doing!
hey
Loop 0 ended.
Type in some string so i can break it: 
there
Loop 1 ended.
Type in some string so i can break it: 
how
Loop 2 ended.
```

The reason why i think this is caused by the scanf line is because the program works fine when i'm using instead some dummy pre-declared String

```
int i = 0;
while(i != 3){
    char str[80] = "hey there how are you doing!";
    testFunc(str);
    printf("Loop %i ended.\n", i);
    i++;
}
return 1;
```

Result:

```
hey
there
how
are
you
doing!
Loop 0 ended.
hey
there
how
are
you
doing!
Loop 1 ended.
hey
there
how
are
you
doing!
Loop 2 ended.
```

Here's the funtion that uses strtok, most of the code here is taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

```
int testFunc(char linha[80]){
    //
   const char s[2] = " ";
   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(linha, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while(token != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", token);

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
   return 1;
}
```

I'm puzzled, it's like the program is executing testFunc() in paralel with the main function.

Comment: If you suspect your `scanf` call fails, did you verify the result? I assume your problem is due to entering spaces.

Comment: I need the spaces, they are supposed to be the strtok delimiter, the strings are supposed to be broken when the program finds a space

Comment: Thanks, it worked... i thought scanf read the entire line but i was wrong.

Comment: it is also possibly worth changing `linha` to be a `char *` so that your compiler won't complain if you pass it in anything other than a `char[80]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is when you execute this loop:

```
while(i != 3){
    printf("Type in some string so i can break it: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    testFunc(str);
    printf("Loop %i ended.\n", i);
    i++;
}
```

`scanf` gets only one word at a time, so the loop cycles 3 times, you only get 3 words no matter how long the input string is.

On the other hand, in your other example you already have a string to break apart so the function will work.

There are different ways to get spaced strings from the console but here is what I consider to be a good option to do it:

```
str[MAX_SIZE];
fgets(str, MAX_SIZE, stdin); 
// where MAX_SIZE is the maximum size you want to allow for the string, 
//must be smaller than str.
```

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) man page:

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next
> pointer must be a pointer to the initial element of a
> character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence
> and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added
> automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at
> the maximum field width, whichever occurs first

You can use fgets or fread for input:

```c
char buffer[1000];
/* fgets (reads a line of text with trailing newline */
fgets (buffer, 1000, stdin);
```